# unable to convert Predicate object to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson, predicate

I'm using this code to convert a nested tree to a JSON file.
every node in the tree contains a Predicate<String[]> Object.
the tree includes all the predicates but the JSON file prints the following:

```
{"predicateId":379,"predicate":{},"label":-1,"yesBranch":
    {"predicateId":490,"predicate":{},"label":-1,"yesBranch": 
        {"predicateId":319,"predicate":{},"label":-1,"yesBranch":{" ...
```

as you can see the predicate field is empty.

the DecisionTree struct:

```
public class DecisionTree {
    private Predicate<String[]> predicate;
    private int label;
    private DecisionTree yesBranch;
    private DecisionTree noBranch;
```

the function I used to convert the tree to JSON is:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(decisionTree);
```

is there a way to print the content of the predicates?
are there different formats I should use instead of JSON?

Comment: Predicate is a function, not a serializable object. They have no content. What are you expecting in the output?

Comment: I'm expecting the lambda of the predicate because I want to transfer it for using it in other programs.

Comment: Methods (lambdas) aren't serializable either... That's like asking for all the methods in your tree class to appear in the json as well

Comment: What I meant - what do you expect the output to look like? For example, a predicate could be something like `"x -> some_logic(x)“`, which is entirely a string, but how would that get parsed back into an actual predicate object?

Comment: exactly like your example `"x -> some_logic(x)“` (as string)

Comment: the compiled bytecode doesn't know what the source looks like. What you need is to define a serializable predicate interface, use that instead, and defined how that serializable gets serialized into json.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe JSON isn't the best, and you could look into other formats that machine learning models use like PMLL, ONXX, etc. Don't have any examples, but those store decision trees somehow